# Chip wan't add to ChipGroup programmatically

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-chips

I have Array list with some values ( Movies categories list ).

I'm trying to add the to ChipGroup programatically, but the are not added.

Look on this method.

```
private void addCategories(MovieDetailsResponse response) {
        ChipGroup chipGroup = mView.findViewById(R.id.categoriesChipGroup);
        for (int i = 0; i < response.getGenres().size()-1; i++) {
            Chip chip = new Chip(chipGroup.getContext());
            chip.setText(response.getGenres().get(i).getName());
            chipGroup.addView(chip);
        }
    }
```

When I debugging this method, so the genres size return me > 0 size ( array have genres ).

But when the debug comes to line `Chip chip = new Chip(chipGroup.getContext());`

The chips are not added and it's throw an Exception :

```
public final class LambdaObserver<T> extends AtomicReference<Disposable>
        implements Observer<T>, Disposable, LambdaConsumerIntrospection {
    @Override
    public void onNext(T t) {
        if (!isDisposed()) {
            try {
                onNext.accept(t);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Exceptions.throwIfFatal(e);
                get().dispose();
                onError(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/movieDetailPosterContainer"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/categoriesChipGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvMovieDetailsTitle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

OOhhh I fixed it with

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                addCategories(response);
            }
        });
```